# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Description'. EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-5.0

I am using Entity Framework Core and I have this model class:

```
public class ConstraintRule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public PlantFilterType PlantFilterType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
    public string PowerplantIds { get; set; } 
    public string PowerplantTypes { get; set; } 
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code in the context related to ConstraintRule model:

```
 builder.Entity<ConstraintRule>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(500);
            entity.Property(e => e.PowerplantIds).HasMaxLength(2000);
            entity.Property(e => e.PowerplantTypes).HasMaxLength(2000);
        });
```

Description is a nullable string, this is the code generated by migration (also `PowerplantIds` and `PowerplantTypes` have the same problem):

```
 migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Description",
            table: "ConstraintRules",
            type: "nvarchar(500)",
            maxLength: 500,
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(500)",
            oldMaxLength: 500,
            oldNullable: true);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Description'

Comment: `nullable: false,` means: the columns is ***NOT*** nullable - hence the error message....

Comment: Look like you enabled nullable reference types. Nevertheless, the default value ("") should prevent this error. So it's hard to tell what's happening here from what you show.

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved by changing string to string?:

```
public string? Description { get; set; }
```

The problem doesn't exist before updating to Dot NET core 5. This is a little confusing because string is a reference type and by default is nullable.

**Edit**: C# 8 introduced a new feature called nullable reference types (NRT), it's value is "annotations" by default (Non-nullable unless declared with ?). To disable this feature open csproj file and edit it:

```
 <PropertyGroup>  
 <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
```

[Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)